# Using embedded Derby with JRuby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, derby

Attempting to use JRuby 1.2.0 and Rails 2.3.2 with an embedded Derby database.  I've copied `derbytools.jar` and `derby.jar` to `$RUBY_HOME/lib`, yet `rake db:migrate` still gives:

```
The driver encountered an error: 
    cannot load Java class org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

Aaaand... I played a hunch and figured it out.  So, I'll post this here in case somebody else runs into the same problem I did.

Almost all the documentation I found online has the following `database.yml` configuration for Derby:

```
development:
    adapter: jdbc
    driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
    url: jdbc:derby:[db];create=true
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
```

This probably works fine for a client/server setup, but for an embedded Derby setup, you need this:

```
development:
    adapter: jdbc
    driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    url: jdbc:derby:[db];create=true
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
```

Note the 'EmbeddedDriver', and not 'ClientDriver'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer, because I hate seeing that red block in my profile.

There's also a subtle bug in ActiveRecord-JDBC when you use embedded derby -- if you don't give it a username and a password, nothing works.  I've tracked down the cause of this bug, and am working on submitting a patch, but if you run into the same problem I did, let me know, and I'll post the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Strange it worked fine for me , on my ubuntu 9.04 box :
i m using only the standard ubuntu packages and my DB configuration is :

```
development:
 adapter: jdbc
 driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
 url: jdbc:derby:[myapp];create=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The ClientDriver is in derbyclient.jar

Answer (score 0):

Further to Don's answer, I was getting this error when using the ClientDriver without a username/password: `The driver encountered an error: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Password length (0) is outside the range of 1 to 255.`

Setting username/password in database.yml fixed the problem!